# An question about the form of a primitive ideal of the bicyclic monoid algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am reading the paper 'Plactic algebra of rank 3'. You can visit http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00233-011-9337-3.
[image]

My question is why the primitive ideal $P$ has the form $(p-\alpha,q-\beta)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K[x,x^{-1}]$ is a commutative PID, and the primitive ideals are necessarily the maximal ideals. Therefore the image in $K[x,x^{-1}]$ (in which $p$ is being mapped to $x$ and $q$ is being mapped to $x^{-1}$) is generated by a single element $x-\alpha$. Of course $\alpha\in K$, and it is impossible for $\alpha$ to be zero since $x$ is a unit and does not generate a proper ideal.

The preimage of $(x-\alpha)$ in $K[B]$ is the ideal $(p-\alpha, 1-qp)$ in $K[B]$.

Then it is an easy matter to compute that

$$
-\alpha^{-1}q(p-\alpha)-\alpha^{-1}(1-qp)=q-\alpha^{-1}\in (p-\alpha, 1-qp)
$$

So it's clear that $(p-\alpha, q-\alpha^{-1})$ is at least a subset. By modifying the string of equalities slightly:

$$
-\alpha^{-1}q(p-\alpha)-(q-\alpha^{-1})=\alpha^{-1}(1-qp)\,;\text{ and }\\
-q(p-\alpha)-\alpha(q-\alpha^{-1})=1-qp
$$

So in fact $(p-\alpha, q-\alpha^{-1})=(p-\alpha, 1-qp)=P$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know why the preimage of $(x-\alpha)$ in $K[B]$ is the ideal $(p-\alpha, 1-qp)$?

Comment: @Daisy  Let $\pi:K[B]/(1-qp)\to K[x;x^{-1}]$ be the surjective ring homomorphism, whose kernel we know to be $(1-qp)$. Obviously $(p-\alpha, 1-qp)$ is a subset of $\pi^{-1}((x-\alpha))$. On the other hand, given $Y$, if you exhibit $X$ such that $\pi(X)=Y$, you know that $\pi^{-1}(Y)=X+\ker(\pi)$. For any particular $(x-\alpha)P[x;x^{-1}]\in (x-\alpha)K[x;x^{-1}]$, it's obvious that $(p-\alpha)P[p;q]$ is a pre-image, so $\pi^{-1}((x-\alpha)K[x;x^{-1}]) = (p-\alpha)P[p;q] + (1-qp)\subseteq (p-\alpha, 1-qp)$. $\pi^{-1}$ of the ideal is the union of these, so you now have the reverse containment.

Comment: There must be some way to simplify it, but this is what I came up with. Intuitively the idea is that you know the entire preimage of the generator of the image, so you must know the entire preimage of the ideal it generates.